# Get a number from your contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I'm trying to access via Intent my contact list in order to get a number but I'm geting an Exception.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

This is my code:

```
// In some function
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Constants.PICK_CONTACT){
        try {

            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
              String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
              // do some stuff
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            Log.i("Excepetion", errors.toString());
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace is this one:

```
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at com.example.example.SendPrivateInfoActivity.onActivityResult(SendPrivateInfoActivity.java:76)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-02 03:17:36.469: I/Excepetion(25527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, ther codes I had seen worked but all contacts were displayed and I only needed the selected. Here, in the same question, the code worked for me:

[Get selected phone number from contacts list without READ_CONTACTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244266/get-selected-phone-number-from-contacts-list-without-read-contacts-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure the contacts you are selecting has a Contact number.This can be done by putting `android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` on third argument of resolver.query().

Secondly try `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` in place of `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER` .

Comment: still, it throws the Exception with the changes you point out :(